# Check remaining time for sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I installed the evaluation version of SQL Server on Ubuntu, which is free for 180 days.

1. How can I check how many days I have left in the trial period?
2. Does that edition have any limitations, such as storage or CPU?
3. How can I enter a serial number to activate SQL Server before (or event after) the 180 days?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways you can check how many days have past since you installed the evaluation edition:

From [Pinal Dave](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/07/13/sql-server-2016-find-expiry-date-developer-edition/):

```
 SELECT create_date                   AS 'SQL Server Installation Date'
      , DATEADD(dd, 180, create_date) AS 'SQL Instance will expire on'
 FROM sys.server_principals
 WHERE NAME = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

Alternative solution - [Finding Your SQL Server Evaluation Time Limit](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/q-finding-your-sql-server-evaluation-time-limit):

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;
RECONFIGURE
GO

DECLARE @RemainingTime INT
DECLARE @InstanceName SYSNAME
SELECT @InstanceName = CONVERT(SYSNAME, SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName'))
EXEC @RemainingTime = xp_qv '2715127595', @InstanceName
SELECT @RemainingTime 'Remaining evaluation days:'

GO
```

The evaluation edition is a full edition without limitation (other than the timeframe you can use it for), as mentioned in the [License section](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) of the Docker hub.

I don't believe you need to enter a serial after you've purchased it (you just need to retain the purchase information Microsoft provides in case you were audited). You can follow [this guide](http://arumel.com/en/sql-server-2017-version-and-license-upgrade-on-linux/) on how to upgrade to a non-evaluation edition.

Answer (score 2):

I would just check the installation date of sql server instance

```
select create_date from sys.server_principals
where name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

and you can see when your instance was installed and then you can figure out how many days are left.

You can find more details from this post
[Is there anyway to know when a sql server instance was installed?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174531/is-there-anyway-to-know-when-a-sql-server-instance-was-installed)